# Nodejs, nodemon app crashed (screenshot inside)

Tags: node.js, server, nodemon

don't understand what's wrong with my server and code. I am passing tutorial and did everything just like in the video but still have the problem

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OCq3.png)

Comment: As the error message stated, OpenWeatherMap refused your connection (and you didn't handle the error gracefully in the code, so it crashed your app instead - my recommendation: Use a library like `node-fetch` to get a less bare-bones interface to HTTP requests, this will also simplify error handling).

Comment: Maybe your IP is blocked on their service? Try from a different computer or with a VPN, and check if the URL you are calling there works in your browser

Comment: @Varikash Can you upload code snippet instead of image so that people can use your code and give solutions on top of YOUR CODE.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using https connection without handling TLS certificates passing.

Here is a code snippet to make you access your openweathermap API without configurating certificates.

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')

const app = express()

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    const url = "<openweathermap>"
    var options = require('url').parse( /**String*/ url );
    options.rejectUnauthorized = false;
    https.get(options, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).on( 'error',function ( e ) {
        console.log(err);
    }).end();

    res.send("Sever up and running");
}

app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log("Server running on port 3000";
}
```

I would suggest to read more on how to setup certificates for HTTPS in Node.JS,
refer this [doc.](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) for more details.

Comment: As i found out, our government is blocking this adress for some reason. The only way to open some pages on openweather map via browser is to use vpn, but how to do that in my server i don't even imagine....but thank you anyway